# Gallery Control - Not working

Tags: android, widget, gallery

When I trying to use Gallery widgets . I have a issue with it .

This class was deprecated in API level 16.
This widget is no longer supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library.

This is my code

```
    String [] text=new String[]{"Hello","Hi","Alloha",
            "Bonjour","Hallo","¡Hola"};

    Gallery gallery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        gallery = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item,text);
        gallery.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

and activity_gallery.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".GalleryActivity" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It displays blank . I'm using android 4.2.2 API 17 . I don't know what happen . Anybody can help me !!!!